# GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user/:id 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm using vue3 with axios and prisma, but I have a problem getting user info.

My postman request is ok (http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user/7), but my axios req is not.

Can you help me please ?

```
        async created () {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user/:id', { 
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
            }
            
        });
        console.log('ici');

        
    }
```

Comment: Did you enable CORS? I had a similar issue but when I allowed all origins in my backend all worked correctly. However, you may want to adjust it to your local host and production URL.

Comment: Likely a CORS issue, your server needs to be configured to accept GET requests from your frontend

Comment: Why do you have `:id` on your axios URL? Have you tried directly with `/7`? Are you sure the token is retrieved correctly from the local storage?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remember to read through the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) which explains how to write a good question. What did you already try/look at/use as tools to figure out what's going wrong? (and put that in your post, don't put that in a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios does not support URL parameters.

One solution would be to use template strings to build the request URL.

For example:

```js
function getID(id) {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user/${id}`,{ 
          headers: {
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
          }  
    });
}

// getID(7);
```

Comment: i have this : GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user/undefined 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: async created (id) {
            const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user/${id}`, { 
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
                }
                
            });

Comment: Are you passing in an id argument when you call this function? 

It looks like you just need to pass in the id when you call.

For example: `created(1)` should change the url to `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user/1`.

Calling `created()` would result in that undefined.

Comment: it is good i have add a const to stock mi id and  parseint